# Cannot get to work Bluetooth LE background trigger with UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

First of all, I can detect perfectly fine the advertisement of my iBeacon on the foreground with `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`. It's just the the trigger for the background is not working with the same parameters. I have declared the background task in the Declarations tab in Package.appxmanifest file, as shown here:

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="App.BluetoothBackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="bluetooth" />
        </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

And this is how I am registering the background task:

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger trigger = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger();
trigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(
    new BluetoothLEManufacturerData() {
        CompanyId = 0x4C
    }
);

BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder {
    Name = "BluetoothWatcher",
    TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BluetoothBackgroundTask).FullName
};
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
builder.Register();
```

I know the task is successfully registered because before registering it, I can find the previous one with the same name and unregister it.

Even I tried filering the ManufacturerData with the Data that is coming from the iBeacon too (that filter worked nice with the foreground watcher too).

So, at this point, I can't think in anything more that I could be doing wrong. I've tried changing the StrengthFilter with some values from the few examples on the Internet, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You code looks correct, I think you could refer [official code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) sample that contains background publisher and watcher.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for your answer, I checked again the docs and found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the issue. The problem is that the way I am registering the background task is for out-of-process tasks. This means that the background task code must be in another project inside the solution instead of being created in the same project as I was doing. It's not so clear that you need to do it, but [the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task#create-the-background-task-class) inside the documentation for out-of-process tasks mentions it.